# How to send and receive formData through fetch to node and express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch, fetch-api, form-data

I am trying to send formData via the fetch API to a node/express app, and use that data to update a database.  I can't access the formData in node.  If someone could kindly point out what I am doing wrong?  I have followed several other answers but none have helped.

I am using javascript to attach an event listener to the submit button, and then access the fetch API.  The code below results in an empty req.body.

**My html form:**

```html
<form
  action=""
  method="POST"
  name="editQuestionForm"
  id="editQuestionForm"
  class="inputForm"
>
  <input
    type="text"
    id="editInputQuestion"
    name="question"
    value=""
    class="formInput"
    placeholder="Question"
  />
  <textarea
    type="text"
    id="editInputAnswer"
    name="answer"
    value=""
    class="formInput"
    placeholder="Answer"
  ></textarea>
  <button id="editQuestionBtn" class="button" type="Submit">
    Edit Question
  </button>
</form>
```

**My javascript:**

```js
const editQuestionForm = document.getElementById("editQuestionForm");
const editQuestionBtn = document.querySelector("#editQuestionBtn");

editQuestionBtn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  id = e.target.getAttribute("data-id");
  updateQuestion(e, id);
});

async function updateQuestion(e, id) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData(editQuestionForm);
  dataToSend = Object.fromEntries(formData);
  await fetch(`/dbControl/editQuestion?id=${id}`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
  });
}
```

**My endpoint in my node/express app:**

```js
router.post("/editQuestion", function (req, res) {
  try {
    console.log(req.body);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } finally {
    res.end();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Content-Type

You aren't sending a FormData object. You are sending JSON.

You are passing a string to the `body` property so you need to explicitly say that you are sending JSON. `fetch` cannot infer that your string is JSON.

This step wouldn't be needed if you were sending multipart form data by passing a FormData object, nor if you were sending URL Encoded data by passing a URLSearchParams object. `fetch` *can* infer the content-type from those objects.

```
await fetch(`/dbControl/editQuestion?id=${id}`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
});
```

## Body Parsing Middleware

As per the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body):

> Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By default, it is undefined, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as express.json() or express.urlencoded().

… you need to include some body parsing middleware.

```
app.use(express.json());
```

(And do it *before* you register the end point handler).

Comment: This worked. I tried to pass the formData object before with `body:formData` instead of `body:JSON.stringify(dataToSend)`, but when I did `console.log(req.body)` gave me an empty object.  Would you mind explaining why?  Is it better to send the formData object?

Comment: It didn’t work because you didn’t have suitable body-parsing middleware (capable of handling a multipart form data request). FormData objects are better if you need to send files (because they support it) but worse in other cases (because multi part mime is a relatively large data format).